# How do I solve this exponential equation???

Tags: algebra-precalculus

\begin{equation} 16^{x}=4^x+3^x \end{equation}
I seem to remember that you have to divide by one of the terms but I don't know what to do after that.

Comment: Are you supposed to find an exact solution?

Comment: Per Fermat's Last Theorem, $x$ will not be an integer.

Comment: You would have to use numerical methods, I suppose.

Comment: @Denis-GeorgeMih Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Note that

- for $x=0 \implies16^{0}=1<2=4^0+3^0$

and

- for $x=1 \implies16^{1}=16>7=4^1+3^1$

thus by IVT we can show that a solution exists in the interval $(0,1)$ and we can show also that it is the unique solution.

We can calulate that value by numerical method (bisection, Newton's, etc.).

Comment: How would you show that it is the only solution?

Comment: By studing the function $f(x)=16^x-4^x-3^x$ and showing that $f'(x)>0$ for $x>0$. For $x<0$ we can set $y=-x$ and study $g(y)=\frac1{16^y}-\frac1{4^y}-\frac1{3^y}$ for $y>0$.

Comment: OK. A heuristic to see that no solution probably exists for $x<0$ is to consider the limit of $|f(x)|$ as $x\to -\infty$. This doesn't really prove anything, though.

Comment: I didn’t try to make that in detail but it could be a good exercise. I’ll try later!

Answer (score 1):

If you consider that you look for the zero of function $$f(x)=16^x-4^x-3^x$$ you could first notice that it is bounded by $16^x-2\times 4^x$ and $16^x-2\times 3^x$ which makes the solution to be
$$\frac{\log (2)}{4 \log (2)-\log (3)} < x < \frac  12$$ which is a quite narrow range; so any method (bisection, Newton, ...) would converge quite fast.

You could even do better, considering instead
$$g(x)=\log(16^x)-\log(4^x+3^x)=4 \log(2) x-\log(4^x+3^x)$$ which is almost a straight line. Being very lazy, make a first order Taylor expansion at $x=0$ (this is the same as one iteration of Newton method using $x_0=0$); it will give
$$g(x)=-\log (2)+ \left(3\log(2)-\frac{1}{2}\log (3)\right)x+O\left(x^2\right)$$ and a "good" estimate is then
$$x = \frac{2 \log (2)}{6 \log (2)-\log (3)}\approx 0.452997$$ A still better approximation would be obtained using the series expansion around $x=\frac 12$, giving
$$g(x)=2 \log (2)-\log \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)+\left(4\log(2)-\frac{4\log(2)+\sqrt 3 \log(3)}{2+\sqrt 3} \right) \left( x-\frac 12\right)+O\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\right)$$ leading to an estimate of $0.454378$.

Using Newton method with $x_0=\frac 12$, the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.50000000000000000000 \\
 1 & 0.45437814464295816356 \\
 2 & 0.45439223471477924666 \\
 3 & 0.45439223471612402617
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for twenty significant figures.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z:=4^x$. The equation can be rewritten

$$z^2=z+z^\alpha$$ or $$z=1+z^{\alpha-1}$$ with $\alpha=\dfrac{\ln 3}{\ln 4}$.

There is no closed-form expression.

Comment: Oh, but now that's beside the point. How does so transforming help?

Comment: Suppose it proves that the solution cannot be expressed in closed form. How does that help anybody? Although the OP did not state it explicitly, I think what is desired is the solution set of the equation.

Comment: The OP expects a solution because they *don't know what to do after that.*

Answer (score 0):

It is a trascendental function which not admits a solution in closed-form. Among the numerical methods to get solution we could note that if 
$$f(x)=16^x-4^x-3^x$$ then $$f(0.45)\approx-0.023337\lt0\lt0.030400\approx f(0.46)$$ It follows there is a root $x_0$ in the  interval of length $0.01$
$$0.45\lt x_0\lt0.46$$ Besides the derivative in this interval is greater than $5$ so the tangent to the curve is very close to the corresponding arc which help to a good approximation.

The solution is unique because both functions $h(x)=16^x$ and $g(x)=4^x+3^x$ are increasing and $h(0)\lt g(0)$ and $h(1)\gt g(1)$.

Comment: The reasons you give for uniqueness don't prove anything since $f(x)$ is not increasing everywhere in $\mathbb R$ as you claim.

Comment: I did not say that $f$ is increasing. See better what you read. The fact is that first $h\lt g$  and then $h\gt g$ both functions being increasing as exponentials.

Comment: My bad. But then you've only shown uniqueness in the interval $(0,1)$, whereas $f$ is defined for all real $x$, see?

Comment: On studying this more closely, your conditions don't prove anything at all, for in general one can construct functions $j$ and $k$ which satisfy your conditions in any closed, bounded interval $[a,b]$ so that $a\ne b$ and $j=k$ as many times as we please in the interval.

Comment: I am from the Scorpio sign. Are you also as I seem to guess when reading your Profile?

Comment: What do you want to Allawonder? that I add to my answer that If $f([n,n+1])=A$ then all the elements of $A$ are positive for $n\ge 1$?. Regards.

Comment: What I want you to see is that you have not proved that there is **only one** solution.

Comment: For example, let $j(x)=x/1000$ and $k(x)=x/1000 + \cos{x/1000}$. Then it is easy to see that both $j$ and $k$ are increasing, and that $j(0)<k(0)$ and $j(π)>k(π)$; yet $j(x)=k(x)$ for infinitely many values of $x$.

Comment: My last reply: our problem is with exponencial functions and not other. Goodbye.

Comment: This is beside the point since you do not mention any other hypothesis apart from the fact that the functions are increasing, and that one is greater than the other at one point, and less at another. You should add some property that certainly proves that the result is unique.